# Dynamic Combo Box Will Not Resize

Tags: c#, .net, forms, user-interface

I'm trying to create a dynamic form. I found this on the web:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/dynamic-controls-cs.htm

and it works. However, I needed to do it with a combo box and it worked, but, I couldn't resize it. Here is my code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKUP3.png)

Any help will be appreciated. As you can see, I tried to resize it before placing it on the form. No compile error. I don't know.

Comment: You mean the height of the comboBox ?

Comment: you may need to provide some code, if you want get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the ComboBox is automatically adjusted to the specified size of the font. You can't change the height unless you increase the font. Like this:

```
box.Font = new Font(box.Font.FontFamily, 16);
```

Comment: Genius! It works! I tried it on a different combo box without having to do that and it worked. Anyhow, I'm glad you were able to get it to work for me. Thanks a million.